# What do you call the objects shown in this picture?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I'm not wrong, the girl shown in the picture below is called 'majorette', a girl who entertains the audience at football games with their spectacular performances,  or something similar. I don't know.

However, what are the things indicated by the red arrows called?

I try to search something, but I didn't have luck.

[image]

Comment: I see majorettes swirl a baton. the above is more likely a cheerleader

Comment: Where in the world did you find that image? Did you draw it?

Comment: @terdon, yes. I'm writing an illustrated fiction narrating of a girl who want to become a majorette.

Comment: Well, that's one hell of an expressive face on your cheerleader! Well done :).

Comment: @mplungjan: I would say "twirl" rather than "swirl".

Comment: You are of course correct

Answer (score 12):

I think they're called [pom poms](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pom%20poms?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic).

Comment: Purists will say *pompons*.

Comment: @GEdgar - I suppose that is a burden they'll have to bear :) Most examples I could find online give the "m" version first which seems to indicate that this variant is most common now.

Comment: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pompoms%2C+pompons%2C+pom+poms&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @mplungjan - Interesting! I hadn't really been aware of the "n" version but then it's not something that you see written down that often and in speech it's very hard to tell the difference.

Comment: I completely agree which is why I posted it :)

Comment: @mplungjan - I keep forgetting to use ngrams - it's one of those things that could easily suck up a load of time if you let it. Thanks!

Comment: The OED gives _pompom_, _pom-pom_, and _pompon_ as current forms (and others, such as _pomponne_ and _pong pong_ as obsolete).

Comment: Also see what happens when you [add a hyphen to the Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pompoms%2Cpompons%2Cpom-poms&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) (though I don’t know if hyphens in Ngrams are reliable or not).

Comment: @GEdgar, Well done. The original word "pompon" comes from French (given away by the "m" before the second 'p') and we stick them on top of "bonnets", and [funnily enough other men's hats](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompon_%28laine%29).

Comment: I wonder if the decline in the usage of _pompoN_ can be attributed to its similarity with _tampon_.

Comment: @terdon - nice theory! It could also be just that pompom is slightly easier to say.

Comment: They are really called "Pom poms": : http://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photography-cheerleaders-pom-poms-raised-portrait-two-happy-against-sky-image30842322

Answer (score 6):

That's not a majorette, that's a cheerleader.  There's a difference.  I shall not explain, but see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorette_%28dancer%29) on this.  The main difference is the pom poms that the girl in the drawing is holding.

That's what those are called (pom po**n**s? what are you people smoking?).

Yes, I'm late with this answer, but I had to do something about the majorette thing.

I can't help commenting further that "majorette" is the feminine version of the title "[drum major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drum_major)", which refers to a man (or these days a woman, too) who leads a marching band.  The majorette provides not direction but entertainment, twirling devices similar to that which a major uses to help convey signals.

Comment: Smoking? Look [here](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompon_%28laine%29) for the "n". This should not surprise you: *-on* is a common augmentative in Romance languages: *carton* (fr) = strong paper (*carta* in Italian), *porcão* (pt) is a large pig, *bigotón* (es): large mustache, etc.

Comment: It was a joke, sorry @AlainPannetierΦ.  Never had heard of the "n" variety before, and it seemed reasonable enough, but I couldn't resist bringing out what I, at least, thought was a funny.  I'm sure you don't smoke anything.

Comment: I probably did not get the joke :) in your otherwise good answer.

Comment: LOL I saw that comment in the inbox, whoever it was who made it then deleted it, about the "herbalist" and smoking!  You should have left it in place; it contributed more humor to the general atmosphere and was thus worthy!  Don't worry, I don't get offended easily, and anyway I am "Cyberherbalist" because I once had a medicinal herb website (kind of like a Wikipedia for herbal medicine).  There is a "cyberherbalist.com" domain that I coined the term for, and it used to belong to me, but I let it go accidentally.  Sigh.

Comment: 'Twas me and I removed it because irrelevancies in the comments are frowned upon by the powers that be. I am also not someone who would be insulted by the accusation of smoking something so I figured I shouldn't fan the flames :).

Comment: +1 for giving me the original chuckle. :-)  And I myself am not particularly impressed by the powers that be.  Humorless prigs, the lot of them!  :-)

Comment: Hmm, should have posted my comment as an answer, but I saw majorettes with pom(-)pon(m)s too

Answer (score 1):

These are called "Cheer Pompons".

For images, please view this link : 
https://www.google.co.in/search?biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&q=cheer+pompons&revid=435032081